# How to calculate the current streak (consecutive days in a row starting at the current date)?

Tags: javascript

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "date": "2019-09-18"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-19"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-21"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-22"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-23"
  }
]
```

```js
function currentStreak(arr) {
  let count = 0
  arr.reverse().forEach((el, i) => {
    if (new Date() - new Date(el.date) === i * 86400000) count++
  })
  return count
}
```

I'm having a hard time getting this to work. Assuming the current date is "2019-09-23", why is the above code returning `0` when it should return `3`?

Comment: `new Date()` is the current date that also includes hours, minutes and seconds. `new Date(el.date)` will return the date at `00:00:00` hours minutes and seconds, so you'll likely never have the `new Date() - new Date(el.date)` will never equal something whole, unless you run this at midnight,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, new Date() gives you date + current time, hence it cannot compare correctly with the New Date(YYYY-MM-DD) which gives time at midnight hours.

If you modify your date to midnight hours, then it will compare correctly. So your code will look like.

```
function currentStreak(arr) {
  let count = 0
  arr.reverse().forEach((el, i) => {
    if ((new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0) - new Date(el.date).setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)) === i * 86400000) count++
  })
  return count
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the current Date i.e today's date - **5th Nov Tue** so the calculation done is on the basis of today's date, you must pass the value of date object

For example :-

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "date": "2019-09-18"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-19"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-21"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-22"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-23"
  }
]

function currentStreak(arr) {
  let count = 0
  arr.reverse().forEach((el, i) => {
    if (new Date('2019-09-23') - new Date(el.date) === i * 86400000) count++
  })
  return count;
}

console.log(currentStreak(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date()` returns [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) - `Tue Nov 05 2019 15:16:22 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)`

So in your if condition it will not increment. Change the format of the `new Date()` and compare it to your array.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "date": "2019-09-18"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-19"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-21"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-22"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-23"
  }
]
function currentStreak(arr) {
  let count = 0
  arr.reverse().forEach((el, i) => {
    if ((new Date() - new Date(el.date) >= i * 86400000) && (new Date() - new Date(el.date) < (i+1) * 86400000))  count++
  })
  return count
}
console.log(currentStreak(arr));
```

It doesn't work because you didn't include minutes, hours, seconds and milliseconds.